# How to I calculate the conditioned probability in this Case?

Tags: probability

Given are $5$ fake dices $A,B,C,D,E$, so they have different probabilities.
Calculate the conditional probability $P(S|A)$ of the sum of all $5$ dices conditioned on the value of the first dice.

In the following I will write the given probabilities for e.g $P(A=a)$ with $a\in \{1,2,...,6\}$ in a List.

$P(A=a) => [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5]$
$P(B=b) => [0.5,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]$
$P(C=c) => [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.1]$
$P(D=d) => [0.1,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]$
$P(E=e) => [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.1]$
with $a,b,c,d,e \in \{1,2,...,6\}$

My question would be. If I want to calculate $P(S = 6|A = 1)$ than it would work like this:

$P(S = 6|A = 1) = P(B=2)*P(C=1)*P(D=1)*P(E=1) + P(B=1)*P(C=2)*P(D=1)*P(E=1) + P(B=1)*P(C=1)*P(D=2)*P(E=1) + P(B=1)*P(C=1)*P(D=1)*P(E=2)$  because $P(S=6|A!=1) = 0$ ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say six dice but then only name 5 of them. In addition, you list 5 different vectors of probabilities but label them all with $P(A=i)$. Please clarify how many dice there are and which probability vectors go with which dice.

Comment: @kccu Im sorry there only 5 dices, I corrected the question.

Comment: @kccu I hope the question  is now understandable ?